# Peak data rate is to whom in LTE?

Tags: wireless

LTE data rate is calculated here.

http://lteuniversity.com/get_trained/expert_opinion1/b/hongyanlei/archive/2010/02/18/how-to-calculate-peak-data-rate-in-lte.aspx.

When we say the peak is 300 Mbps( under some specific configuration such as 4 * 4 MIMO), are we referring to a user who will experience 300Mbps or is it an aggregate data rate of all users in the cell? because, in the calculation, all the resource blocks have been used up.

Thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the total throughput of the cell. A single user could use up all that or it could be divided over many users. Do note that when you have multiple users you are likely to have more overhead in various reasons so total throughput will go down.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically "Yes" , including conditions that 'UE' that means mobile phone is capable of receiving 4*4 and radio conditions are favorable. This 300Mbps also consists overhead in form of control signalling and measurement information for UE about 50 Mbps. If more than one users are there in one cell it will distributed among other UEs too .